# Comparing two files and output the difference into a thrid file via Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, findstr

So the scenario I am tackling is that I have two files. File 1 contains a lot of log entries with error code values at different junctures. File 2 contains error code values listed which are already known to us. A batch file when run would go through file 1 and list out the entries which has errorcode different to what are listed in file 2. For eg,

```
File 1:
We have errorcode: 3 here
this entry contains errorcode:9
errorcode: 5 for this entry

File 2:
errorcode: 3
errorcode: 5

File 3:
this entry contains errorcode:9
```

The code I am using in batch file is as following:

```
@findstr /i /L "errorCode: " "File 1.txt"|@findstr /V /G:"File 2.txt">>File 3.txt
```

However, it's giving me an error of "Line xxxx is too long" while executing whenever the file sizes are big. Now I have to deal with files as large as 300 MB for this scenario. Is there any adjustment I could make?

[image: Here is a sample of the error]

Comment: How long is line xxxx?  Was it a match or not?  Does findstr bail out as soon as it hits the long line or does it continue after?

Comment: It continues after giving the same error repeatedly. The values are varying for eg. 1653, 1757, etc.